# What can go wrong with file.renameTo(file) in Android

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, file-rename

I'm reading the documentation of `renameTo(File)` in the `File.class` of the [Android SDK doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29).

We've been using this method for a while in production, still I have been wondering what are the possible things that can go wrong. The documentation says

Renames this file to newPath. This operation is supported for both files and directories.

> Many failures are possible. Some of the more likely failures include:
>
> - Write permission is required on the directories containing both the source and destination paths.
> - Search permission is required for all parents of both paths.
> - Both paths be on the same mount point. On Android, applications are most
>     likely to hit this restriction when attempting to copy between
>     internal storage and an SD card. Note that this method does not throw
>     IOException on failure. Callers must check the return value.

What are other possible reasons why `renameTo()` might fail (referring to *more likely failures*)? Is there a guaranteed state after calling `renameTo`? When `renameTo()` fails, can I rely on having still my original file? Any other conditions I want to check to uber sure that it works beside the described ones from the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android File.renameTo calls Linux rename() (via libcore). You can check [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) for the list of possible failures, it may be slightly different on Linux, but should give you general idea.

Also note this statement:

> If the rename() function fails for any reason other than [EIO], any file named by new shall be unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

The three that are listed are the *more likely* failures. Less likely (but possible!) failures include

- user error (e.g. source is a file and destination is an existing directory, or vice versa)
- no space left on device
- file system mounted read-only
- corrupt file system
- bad sector on rotational disk
- ...

As Android is based on Linux you can probably rely on these though:

- if rename fails both files are left as they were
- if the destination file exists, and rename succeeds, at no point will any process find the destination file missing (the replacement is atomic)

Answer (score 1):

For the reason that I don't know, it's not possible to use file.rename() to move files between to different mounted directory in Android (like sdcard0 and sdcard1), here is my solution and it work for me:

```
if(canRename(f1, f2)) {
    if(!f1.renameTo(f2)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error to move new app: " + f1 + " > " + f2);
    }
} else {
    try {
        copy(f1, f2);
        f1.delete();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error to move new app: " + f1 + " > " + f2);
    }
}

private void copy(final File f1, final File f2) throws IOException {
    f2.createNewFile();

    final RandomAccessFile file1 = new RandomAccessFile(f1, "r");
    final RandomAccessFile file2 = new RandomAccessFile(f2, "rw");

    file2.getChannel().write(file1.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, f1.length()));

    file1.close();
    file2.close();
}

private boolean canRename(final File f1, final File f2) {
    final String p1 = f1.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("^(/mnt/|/)", "");
    final String p2 = f2.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("^(/mnt/|/)", "");

    return p1.replaceAll("\\/\\w+", "").equals(p2.replaceAll("\\/\\w+", ""));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That rename does not work between different mount points is clear from the documentation. The question was aimed to learn about what else can go wrong.

Comment: @user1079877 I have used your code to rename image on broadcastreceiver, it worked perfectly until android 6, as you know permission is checked at runtime, so now f2.createNewFile();
 raise exception for access denied, do you have any offer?